# How to find $\textsf T^t$ on $\mathbb R^2$, equipped with the standard inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators, transpose

When given a linear operator $\textsf T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by 
$$\textsf T(x,y) = (x+y,x+2y)$$ 
How can I find $\textsf T^t$ on the standard inner product space $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: what is small t?

Comment: Write $T$ as a matrix and compute write down what its transpose is doing.

Comment: @Riquelme t means transpose.

Comment: @Hanno Why did you change the $T^t$ to $T^T$?

Comment: I edited to use "\top" for transpose. Hope it helps.

Comment: @JonathanZ: Ugh.

Comment: @Hanno $T^t$ and ${}^t T$ (or maybe $\tilde{T}$) are common as well. It's like changing the $\tan$ to $\operatorname{tg}$ or a $\log$ to $\ln$ (or vice versa). I think it's up to the op to decide his/her notation in the question, and he/she picked the $T^t$.

Comment: Wow, the notation for transpose turns out to be much more controversial than I had expected. Lower case "$t$" looks like an exponent to me too, but I guess we've ended up on that. The crowd has spoken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that by *transpose* of a linear operator $\textsf T$, on a inner product space $( \textsf V , \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle )$, you mean that the linear operator $\textsf T^t$ such that
$$\langle x,\textsf T^t(y) \rangle = \langle \textsf T(x),y \rangle$$
for all $x$ and $y$ on $\textsf V$.

In your concrete example, following the definition, fix $(y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb R^2$ and for all $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2$ we have that
$$\langle (x_1,x_2),\textsf{T}^t(y_1,y_2) \rangle = \langle \textsf{T}(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2) \rangle = \langle (x_1+x_2,x_1+2x_2),(y_1,y_2) \rangle = (x_1+x_2)y_1+(x_1+2x_2)y_2 = x_1(y_1+y_2)+x_2(y_1+2y_2) = \langle (x_1,x_2),(y_1+y_2,y_1+2y_2) \rangle$$
Thus,
$$\textsf{T}^t(y_1,y_2) = (y_1+y_2,y_1+2y_2)$$
As you can see, in this particular case, $\textsf T^t = \textsf T$.